# Should i put [RequireComponent(typeof())] on top of every derived class

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

For example i have these classes :

```
[RequireComponent(typeof(EquipmentsManager))]
public class PlayerView : MonoBehaviour { }

public class OpponentView : PlayerView { }
```

I want my OpponentView to also have this dependency

```
[RequireComponent(typeof(EquipmentsManager))]
```

Should i put this on top of every class? or if i put this on top of my base class it will be fine?

Thanks

Comment: Depends where the needs occurs. If in base then put it in base. If some subs wont need then it should go for those in need.

Comment: Yes i need it on all derived classes and base class

Comment: So put it on the top class. The bonus is that if you were to change the class of the dependency, you only change it in one place instead of 5, 10 or 100.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you put `[RequireComponent(typeof())]` on top of base calss it we be needed dependency for all derived classes.

so putting `[RequireComponent(typeof(EquipmentsManager))]` on top of `PlayerView` should be enough.

Thanks to Everts.